# How I cant take off appcompat from my application in android?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Long time i didnt used android, now when I back this appcompat are confusing me. I have searched about it, but I didnt liked, its unused for.
I want to know how can I take this off? if possible.

Comment: How are you creating your project? Are you using Eclipse or Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

If your refer to the `support library`, You only have to remove it from your application build path and substitute all the elements that used the library. For example, Instead of using `ActionBarActivity`, you use now `Activity`. Instead of `FragmentActivity`, you use `Activity` and so on.

Make sure you organize your imports in order to remove the ones from the support library.

Answer (score -1):

Just click 
Project > Android > Fix Project Properties.

It worked on Eclipse Kepler and latest ADB version !

or

**step 1:** untick the **create new activity** checkbox, when creating a new project..

**step 2:** create java file and xml file manually.